# Regex to parse file name in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse a file name according to a given pattern but not able to perfect the match. Here is a sample file name:

```
CRS-ISAU-RPV#3430_Dedalus_Conc.ok.erto_AOTreviglio.doc
```

And here are my requirements:

til the character `#` the file name can contain anything, after `#`, i have to find character `_` or the character `-` to separate a string. The string in between the character(optionally `_` or `-` - but not both) can contain any other character. So eventually after the character `#` i must have exactly three (3) `_` or `-` characters combined. The string should end with `.doc` or `.docx` or `.odt` but NOT `.ok.doc` or `.ok.docx` or `.ok.odt`.

Here is what i tried:

```
(.*)#([^_-]+)[_-]([^_-]+)[_-]([^_-]+)[_-]([^_-]+)\.[doc|odt|docx].*(?<!\.ok)$
```

But this forces me to end the string with `.doc.ok` or `.docs.ok` or `.docx.ok` and actually i want to retain the file extension at the end.

If i try this:

```
(.*)#([^_-]+)[_-]([^_-]+)[_-]([^_-]+)[_-]([^_-]+)\..*(?<!ok\.[doc|odt|docx])$
```

it wont work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: The syntax `[doc|odt|docx]` doesn't do what you appear to think it does. Try replacing the `[]` with a non-capturing group: `(?:)`

Comment: Try [`"^([^#]*#[^-_]*)[-_](.*)$(?:(?<=(?<!\\.ok)\\.docx$)|(?<=(?<!\\.ok)\\.doc$)|(?<=(?<!\\.ok)\\.odt$))"`](https://regex101.com/r/eH3wY2/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/ this link throws an error for what you are suggesting.

Comment: No, there, you need to insert a single-backslashed version: `(?m)^([^#]*#[^-_]*)[-_](.*)$(?:(?<=(?<!\.ok)\.docx$)|(?<=(?<!\.ok)\.doc$)|(?<=(?<!\.ok)\.odt$))` - or even simpler `(?m)^([^#]*#[^-_]*)[-_](.*)$(?<=(?<!\.ok)\.(?:docx?|odt)$)` works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can use

```
^([^#]*#[^-_]*)[-_](.*)$(?<=(?<!\.ok)\.(?:docx?|odt)$)
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string (not necessary when used with `.matches()`, but not harmful)
- `([^#]*#[^-_]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ characters other than `#` (`[^#]*`) followed with `#` and then any 0+ characters iother than `-` and `_` (with `[-_]`)
- `(.*)$` - match 0+ characters other than a newline (since DOTALL mode is not specified) up to the end of string BUT...
- `(?<=(?<!\.ok)\.(?:docx?|odt)$)` - after reaching the end, check if there is `.doc` or `.docx` or `.odt` at the end (see `(?<=\.(?:docx?|odt)$)`) that are not preceded with `.ok` (see `(?<!\.ok)`). In PCRE, these conditions should be split, Java regex seems to cope with alternations inside the lookbehind.

**A lookahead-based alternative**:

```
^([^#]*#[^-_]*)[-_](?=.*(?<!\.ok)\.(?:docx?|odt)$)(.*)$
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1sG0/1). It is the same, but all the end-of-string checks are done after matching the `-` or `_`.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/iLoZWH):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("CRS-ISAU-RPV#3430_Dedalus_Conc.ok.erto_AOTreviglio.doc",
            "CRS-ISAU-RPV#3430_Dedalus_Conc.ok.erto_AOTreviglio.docx",
            "CRS-ISAU-RPV#3430_Dedalus_Conc.ok.erto_AOTreviglio.odt",
            "CRS-ISAU-RPV#3430_Dedalus_Conc.ok.erto_AOTreviglio.ok.docx",
            "CRS-ISAU-RPV#3430_Dedalus_Conc.ok.erto_AOTreviglio.ok.odt"
        );
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println("----------\nMatching: " + str);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^([^#]*#[^-_]*)([-_])(.*)$(?<=(?<![.]ok)[.](?:docx?|odt)$)").matcher(str);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
    } else { System.out.println("No match"); }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. It misses one thing though in the question: " i must have exactly three (3) _ or - characters combined." Which means, collectively there has to be 3 `_` or `-` Summing up the two characters, they must be as a whole 3. And in between these characters will be strings of any sort BUT not containing `#`. The sample file name(String) shows that there are 3 `_` but you can replace any `_` with `-` and yet it should be a match.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/cC2wF4/1)? `^([^#\n]*#[^-_\n]*)[-_](?=(?:[^-_\n]*[_-]){3}[^-_\n]*$)(?=.*(?<!\.ok)\.(?:docx?|odt)$)(.*)$` (for testing) and `"^([^#]*#[^-_]*)[-_](?=(?:[^-_]*[_-]){3}[^-_]*$)(?=.*(?<![.]ok)[.](?:docx?|odt)$)(.*)$"` (for using in code).

Comment: I solved it with the help of your answer. I will mark your answer as correct :) Thanks a lot!